# localhost refused to connect Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, localhost, iis-express

I've been working on a website using ASP.NET MVC, and I have this page in the website where you can directly send the a email form to a specific email address. Before I don't have database for the form, and it's working perfectly the form is sending without any problem but when I tried to add a database for it (cause I want the information to be save at the database at the same time send it) and tried to send it I keep on having this error:[image]

But when I go to the other page it's working properly. I'm not really sure what the problem is cause I'm new with this kind of stuffs, but maybe the problem is related to this class:

```
public class RegisterRepository
{
    //SqlTransaction transaction = null;
    private SqlConnection con;
    //To Handle connection related activities
    private void connection()
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString();
        con = new SqlConnection(constr);

    }


    public bool Register(TalentInfo model)
    {
        connection();

        try
        {
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SP_INSERT_TALENT_INFO", con);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Talent_Name", model.Talent_Name);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Talent_Email", model.Talent_Email);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Talent_SelfPromotion", model.Talent_SelfPromotion);
            con.Open();
            int i = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            if (i >= 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {

                return false;
            }


        }

        catch
        {
            return Register(model);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }

    }


}
```

I tried repairing my IIS 8.0 Express, (SSL Enable = True), and other solutions but it still doesn't work. Please someone help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: In you code you are using "DefaultConnection" as your connection string.Check whether it is valid as it is the default connection string provided.

Comment: check "DefaultConnection" connectionstring is present in your web.config?

Comment: The "DefaultConnection" is present in my Web.config

Comment: Please debug the website and post the stack trace. It sounds to me like a configuration problem.

Comment: @Eric Is this the stack trace Sir? 

**Detailed Error Information:**
**Module**    IIS Web Core
**Notification**    Unknown
**Handler**    Not yet determined
**Error Code**    0x8007000d
**Config Error**    Only one <configSections> element allowed. It must be the first child element of the root <configuration> element
**Requested URL**    http://localhost:55471/
**Physical Path**    
**Logon Method**    Not yet determined
**Logon User**    Not yet determined

Comment: I would say you have just discovered a (hopefully *the*) problem. The error clearly indicates your `web.config` has more than one `<configSections>` element. You must merge the contents of both elements into one section that *must* be immediately after the `<configuration>` element.

Comment: @NightOwl888 It still not working Sir.

Comment: @NightOwl888 Sir when I tried to delete the RegistrationRepository class, the email is sending and at the same time it's saving in the database. Do you have any idea for it? Thank you.